# Is it possible to set true by default in shopify boolean metafiled?

Tags: shopify

I have set metafiled, which has a boolean type. Now I want to set that metafiled's value by default true. From shopify admin side(custom data) it is not possible. But is there any possibility here?

Is it possible or not. and if it is, then How can I do that?