# Is it possible to set true by default in shopify boolean metafield?

Tags: shopify

I have set metafield which has type boolean, now I want to set it's value by default true for all prodcuts. By admin side(custom data), it is not possible. So is it possible or not and if it is then how can I do it?

Is it possible or not and if it is then how can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to set true by default in shopify boolean metafiled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77877724/is-it-possible-to-set-true-by-default-in-shopify-boolean-metafiled)